# Using an image as an class object attribute, then opening that image in a Tkinter label widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I'm new to python and have been messing around with Tkinter and now Pillow.

I'm trying to make an image an attribute of a class, and then have that image open as an image in a Tkinter Label. Here's some sample code. My Tkinter windows are working right aside from when I try to do this exact thing, so if there are any errors in the Tkinter code below it's purely as a result of writing samples.

```
class PicTest:
    def __init__(self, name, image):
        self.name = name
        self.image = image

foo = PicTest('foo', Image.open('foo.png'))
```

This opens the image in a new window

```
foo.image.show()
```

But this throws an error when I try to run it.

```
def testwindow:
    root = Tk()

    <necessary code>

    foo_testlabel = Label(root, image=foo.image, height=xxx, width=xxx)
    foo_testlabel.pack()

    mainloop()
```

The error that I get is:

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=119x96 at 0x10D9FE240>" doesn't exist
```

I've successfully achieved the result I want NOT using this method (using PhotoImage(file=xxxx) to open whatever I want within my Tkinter definition) but ideally the image is an attribute of the object so I can use it elsewhere.

Any thoughts of the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Standard PIL/Pillow `Image` objects are not compatible with Tkinter.  You have to explicitly convert them to `ImageTk` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "create" the `PhotoImage` of the file and then store it in `self.image` and then use that whenever needed. Here is an example.

```
import tkinter as tk

class PicTest:
    def __init__(self, name, image):
        self.name = name
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image)

root = tk.Tk()
foo = PicTest('foo', '/path/to/image/file')

def testwindow():
    foo_testlabel = tk.Label(root, image=foo.image)
    foo_testlabel.pack()

testwindow()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i had done something like that as well, which worked: pulling the file I need, then assigning, then placing that inside my label.

I'm actually working on a board game (as an exercise as I learn) and there are lots of little pieces and things that get refreshed over the game. Therefore, I'm really hoping to assign an image to an object attribute to call on demand without any additional steps, since there will be so many floating around!

If that's not possible, this method will work fine, I'll just have to loop it to populate the images that I need.

Comment: @Jonathan Edited my answer. Have a look now.

Comment: Thank you! That's also very helpful, I like that. In that way, the Tk root window is actually part of the main code, and not the function, correct?